# How to calculate a moving average over a year with unevenly spaced dates in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have some data that I want to calculate the moving average of over a year's time. If the data was always sampled at the same rate and there were the same number of cells included each time, I could just use the offset function, but this is not the case. I currently am just using the average funcntion and changing the cells as I insert a new row. I would like to be able to reference the dates on the left in order to find the average of the data points that are in the last year without having to change the cells referenced in the equation every time. I would need to do something similar in an 80% confidence interval equation I have. Unfortunately I have just created a stack overflow account, as I usually can find an answer online somewhere, so I do not have enough rep to add a picture. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a conditional average where:

- Start date is greater than the date 1 year prior to date
- End date is equal to date

Assuming dates in column A and values in column B then you can use the AVERAGEIFS function as follows:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">"&EDATE(A250,-12),$A:$A,"<="&A250)
```

EDATE(Date, Months) returns the date that is Months before or after Date.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This seems to be exactly what I need, but I will let you know for sure whether or not it works when I get a chance to try it out!